# Linq to Entities SQL generation issue

Tags: vb.net, t-sql, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I have a VB.Net Linq to Entities query that returns data back from SQL Server 2005. If I copy the query into LinqPad it works as expected but when I attempt to run the code it returns all the counts equal to 1.

The only thing that changes is the date values are dummied in LinqPad and passed through as parameters in VB.

Any ideas what is wrong?

Date parameters from the ViewModel are as below and should represent Jan 1st 2011 --> Feb 1st 2011

?startDate
"#1/1/2011#"
?endDate
"#2/1/2011#"

```
Public Function GetPLMNewPartCounts(ByVal startDate As Date, ByVal endDate As Date) As IEnumerable(Of NewPartsCounts)

        Return From i In ObjectContext.tblEngineeringDashboard_ItemList
                    Join t In ObjectContext.tblTimes On t.ID Equals i.TimeID
                    Join b In ObjectContext.tblEngineeringDashboard_Business On b.ID Equals i.BusinessID
                    Where t.Period >= startDate And t.Period <= endDate
                    Group b By Key = b.BusinessUnit Into Group
                    Select New NewPartsCounts With {.BusinessUnit = Key,
                                                    .NewPartsCount = Group.Select(Function(c) c.BusinessUnit).Distinct().Count()}

End Function
```

TSQL from SQL profiler

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
1 AS [C1], 
[Project4].[BusinessUnit] AS [BusinessUnit], 
[Project4].[C1] AS [C2]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Project2].[BusinessUnit] AS [BusinessUnit], 
    (SELECT 
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT 
            [Extent6].[BusinessUnit] AS [BusinessUnit]
            FROM   [dbo].[tblEngineeringDashboard_ItemList] AS [Extent4]
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[tblTime] AS [Extent5] ON [Extent4].[TimeID] = [Extent5].[ID]
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[tblEngineeringDashboard_Business] AS [Extent6] ON [Extent4].[BusinessID] = [Extent6].[ID]
            WHERE ([Extent5].[Period] >= @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent5].[Period] <= @p__linq__1) AND ([Project2].[BusinessUnit] = [Extent6].[BusinessUnit])
        )  AS [Distinct2]) AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Distinct1].[BusinessUnit] AS [BusinessUnit]
        FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT 
            [Extent3].[BusinessUnit] AS [BusinessUnit]
            FROM   [dbo].[tblEngineeringDashboard_ItemList] AS [Extent1]
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[tblTime] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[TimeID] = [Extent2].[ID]
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[tblEngineeringDashboard_Business] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[BusinessID] = [Extent3].[ID]
            WHERE ([Extent2].[Period] >= @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent2].[Period] <= @p__linq__1)
        )  AS [Distinct1]
    )  AS [Project2]
)  AS [Project4]',N'@p__linq__0 datetime,@p__linq__1 datetime',@p__linq__0='2011-01-01 00:00:00:000',@p__linq__1='2011-02-01 00:00:00:000'
```

Comment: My fault. Forgot to remove the .Distinct. DOH!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fault. Forgot to remove the .Distinct. DOH!!!